# OR condition in return statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, logic

How i can put a OR condition in "return statement"

```
 isFileValid() {        
        return this.myUploadCtrl.nativeElement.value.indexOf("csv") != -1
    }
```

I want to validate csv as well as CSV in capitals

I know how to do this using if else.

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a case-insensitive regular expression:

```
isFileValid() {
  return /csv/i.test(this.myUploadCtrl.nativeElement.value)
}
```

Demo:

```js
function isFileValid(value) {
  return /csv/i.test(value)
}
console.log(isFileValid('csv'));
console.log(isFileValid('csV'));
console.log(isFileValid('CSV'));
console.log(isFileValid('CSVV'));
console.log(isFileValid('VVVV'));
```

If you don't want to match patterns like `cSV` and `CSv`, you could do something similar:

```
isFileValid() {
  return /csv|CSV/.test(this.myUploadCtrl.nativeElement.value)
}
```

Demo:

```js
function isFileValid(value) {
  return /csv|CSV/.test(value)
}
console.log(isFileValid('csv'));
console.log(isFileValid('csV'));
console.log(isFileValid('CSV'));
console.log(isFileValid('CSVV'));
console.log(isFileValid('VVVV'));
```

Comment: I added live snippets to demonstrate so you can see for yourself - it *does* work.

Answer (score 2):

use a condition like in a regular if condition

```
return (expression1 || expression2)
```

Comment: return (this.myUploadCtrl.nativeElement.value.indexOf("csv") != -1 || this.myUploadCtrl.nativeElement.value.indexOf("CSV") != -1)  i tried this both values csv and CSV it showing false, i am expecting true when i put csv or CSV